# I ran into a problem while creating my own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system

I'm making my own shell in C. The input window appears, but when I enter the command `ls`, it does not respond.

```
#define MAX 64
char buf[MAX];
void * get_next_command(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        while(1){
                char *cmd = get_next_command();
                int child_pid = fork();
                
        if(child_pid <0){
            perror("error\n");
            return -1;
        }
        else if(child_pid == 0){
                        execle(cmd,cmd,NULL);
                    exit(0);
        }
                else{
                        wait(NULL);
                }
                
        }
    return 0;
}

void * get_next_command()
{
    printf("Shell > ");
    fgets(buf,MAX,stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\n';
}
```

I wonder how to run commands in my own shell. Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

Comment: What does gdb tells you? If, for some reason, you can't use gdb(or any other debugger), there is always printf...

Comment: There were no error messages from mobaxterm. However, "Shell >" appears and I typed "ls", but the file list did not appear.

Comment: I downvoted, so others just pass these questions.

Comment: `execle` returns -1 on error and sets `errno`, have you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

While making a shell seems simple, you actually have to work a bit more on this to make it work. The thing is execle asks for the **path** of the file to execute. For example ls is actually `/bin/ls` so that's what you need to pass on as a first argument for your program to work. If you wanna go deeper into this and make a real custom shell, you have to get your environment through your main like this:

```
int main(int ac, char **av, char **env);
```

This will get your environment (you can type env in your terminal to see what it's like) then you'll be able to get the PATH variable to get all the paths separated by `:` for your binaries (like /bin which is used by /bin/ls).

As for execle, if you wanna pass on the arguments you have, you have to pass them like this:

For example if the command is `ls -l -a`
then you will run:

```
execle("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "-a", NULL);
```

But you can also do the same with execv which works with a char ** instead of strings for your arguments. AND if you go even deeper into this you can pass on your custom environment with execve (the third argument being your environment).

Here's how you should call your function (replacing the hardcoded values by variables of course):